# Ratio of two normal random variables with the same mean and same standard deviation

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, ratio

I would like to compute the probability density function of $Z = \dfrac{X}{Y}$ with $X$ and $Y$ following a non-standard normal distribution with the same parameters (same mean and variance).

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: Yes they are independent.

Comment: Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution